# AT Command Equivalents to libqmi

Tags: lte, libqmi, telit

I am integrating an LTE modem with the Telit LE910C1-WWX with an embedded device with Linux OS. The module uses a Qualcomm MDM9207 chip. Linux instantiates a wwan0 interface using the qmi_wwan kernel driver. I can use the modem with libqmi, but we support other Intel-based Telit modules that require the use of AT commands. In order to prevent the addition of another third-party package (libqmi) and keep the interface in line with our other modems, I would prefer to use AT commands only.

Is there an equivalent AT command combination for the following qmicli command?

```
qmicli --device=/dev/cdc-wdm0 --device-open-proxy --wds-start-network="ip-type=4,apn=<our_apn>" --client-no-release-cid
```

I have tried switching the modem to ECM mode. And using AT#ECM=3,0. This succeeds and I can get the IP information from AT#CGCONTRDP=3. I configure the linux host in the same manner I've done with othe telit modules in NCM mode, but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Dang you could do with it with a windows power shell command (WShell) but I don't know if linix has a way to do that, I hope it does... its times like these the cost savings from not purchasing an os start to become arbetrary.